# Where can I find a description of Swing as a single-threaded model in the JavaDoc?

Tags: swing, javadoc

It's widely known that Swing uses a single Event Dispatch Thread. Where can I find a statement that says this in the JavaDoc?

I can find a blog entry from Sun that says this:

> This analysis culminated in one of the design reviews for Swing in
>   1997, when we reviewed the state of play in AWT, and the overall
>   industry experience, and we accepted the Swing team's recommendation
>   that Swing should support only very limited multi-threading. With a
>   few narrow exceptions all GUI toolkit work should occur on the event
>   processing thread. Random threads should not try to directly
>   manipulate the GUI state.

-- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kgh/archive/2004/10/multithreaded_t.html

But since blog entries are not documentation, I don't want to rely on what might simply be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [swing package javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading), which is linked from the javadoc of **every** Swing component. See for example the [doc of JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html), which says:

> Warning: Swing is not thread safe. For more information see Swing's Threading Policy.

Comment: Thanks for helping me find what a general web search couldn't. It's greatly appreciated.