# What are the thread command alternatives in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am dealing with threads and I want to run this code whenever I open `Cal_JInternalFrame`. It runs the fist time, but whenever I reopen the frame, it doesn't run again. I use `t1.interrupted()` at exit time of the whole application. The code is:

```
Thread t1 =  new Thread( new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while ( !t1.isInterrupted() ) {    
            // ......... Oil Calculation Thread ... 
            int price = (Integer.parseInt(jLabel22.getText()));
            int qty = (Integer)jSpinner8.getValue();
            int totalOil =qty * price;
            jTextField19.setText(String.valueOf(totalOil));       
        }
    }
});
```

`t1.start()` is in the constructor of the main frame.

The thread primitive methods `destroy()`, `stop()`, `resume()`, and `suspend()` have been deprecated, so I can't use those. How can I `stop` and `resume` a thread now? And if my thread `t1` is interrupted, how can it be resumed or run again?

Comment: Maybe a Future is what you're looking for.

Comment: Your code is *wrong* on a different level than you assume: Swing is **not thread-safe** and you are not allowed to query or modify any Swing components from any thread except the UI thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873198/where-can-i-find-a-description-of-swing-as-a-single-threaded-model-in-the-javado You can use `EventQueue.invokeLater` and `EventQueue.invokeAndWait` to schedule code to run on the UI thread if you are currently on a different thread. Failure to do so breaks your program in very unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads cannot be re-used. For tasks that require to be executed on a separate thread at different times, use a single thread executor.

It seems like you need a worker thread. Since standard threads are not reusable without extra work, we use worker threads to manage tasks that should be executed multiple times.

```
ExecutorService executors = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

With this, you can reuse a single thread to execute code multiple times. It also allows you to make asynchronous callbacks using Future like this:

```
class Demo {
     static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          Future<String> result = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
               public String call() {
                    //do something
                    return "Task Complete";
               }
          });

          try {
               System.out.println(result.get()); //get() blocks until call() returns with its value
          }catch(Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
}
```

You can now re-use `executor` for the task that you want. It accepts `Runnable` through it's `execute(Runnable)` method.

I see you're using Swing. Post all swing code to the Event Dispatch Thread using `EventQueue.invokeLater(Runnable)`. `getText()` and `setText()` should be called on the Event Dispatch Thread to avoid inconsistancies.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop and resume a thread now?

You can't.  Instead, you need to make your thread stop and resume itself.  For example:

```
private boolean wake;

public synchronized void wakeup() {
    this.wake = true;
    this.notify();
}

public void run() {
    while ( !t1.isInterrupted() ) {    
        // do stuff ...
        wake = false;
        synchronized (this) {
            while (!wake) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    t1.interrupt();  // reset the interrupted flag
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When some other thread wants to get this one to do something, the calls the `wakeup()` method on the extended runnable object.

> And if my thread t1 is interrupted, how can it be resumed or run again?

As you have written it, No.  Once the thread returns from the `run()` method call, it cannot be restarted.  You would need to create and start a brand new `Thread`.

---

However, what you are trying to do is unsafe.  As @Erwin points out, it is not safe for the `t1` thread to be calling methods on Swing objects such as `jTextField19`.  You should only call methods on Swing objects from the Swing event dispatching thread.

Reference:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)